# Filtering a buffer with words and numbers into a buffer for only words, and a buffer for only numbers

Tags: c

I'm trying write a C script that can interpret blank spaces separated by commas as zeros, and then porting into a program that I'm working on. The program will be reading CSV files, which uses commas between words and numbers.

I want to separate words from numbers and put them in two separate buffers to be later read with scanf statements.

As of now, I get this when compiling and running the script:

```
Frank    (0 Value)

John     (0 Value)

sir      (0 Value)

45       (45 Value)

21       (21 Value)

-- (0 Value)

79       (79 Value)
```

I only want words in the left column and numbers in the right Value column. Not necessary printed that way, but separated into two buffers.

```
<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer_lines[] = "Frank,John,sir,45,21,,79"; //read, sort, read, sort, use only 2D array
    char sub_buffer_lines[20] = "";
    int subindex = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j == 0) {

    if(buffer_lines[i] != ',' && buffer_lines[i] != '\0') {
        sub_buffer_lines[subindex] = buffer_lines[i];
        sub_buffer_lines[subindex + 1] = '\0';
        subindex++;
    }

    else{
        sub_buffer_lines[subindex] = '\0';
        int value = 0;
        if(0 != subindex)
        {
            value = atoi(sub_buffer_lines);
        }
        printf("\n%s", sub_buffer_lines);//only for names
        printf("     %d Value", value);//only for numbers
        subindex = 0;
        }

        if(buffer_lines[i]=='\0'){
            j = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any logic checking the input for digits or otherwise. Shouldn't that be a critical function?

Comment: The program I'm writing is a grade calculator. It has to take in the student names and their grades. Wait, since the first and last name is always the first two inputs for every line in the input file that I was given, I could create a small buffer to read the first two things (the name), and then a larger buffer to read all of the numbers. D'oh. Nevertheless, I wonder how do I separate words from numbers in a buffer?

Comment: do you want `{{Frank,45},{John,21},{sir,79}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Just think what needs to be done when you get  ','. You may have to add else if rather than just stopping at else.

Comment: Hm. Good point. I want the program to interpret the ',' as a sign to move onto reading the next word or number. I'm trying to think of something.